# SQL Server Memory Configuration

Tags: sql-server-2014

My Server has Total RAM 200GB.

I have set 80% of total RAM for SQL Server as it needs more memory.

Just want to know if there is any fixed number or method to finalise amount of memory to be set for SQL Server and then lock pages for SQL Server (or) it depends completely on resource utilization,workload?

Comment: You need to take help of permon counters to set appropriate value for Buffer pool leaving behind enough for OS to function properly

Comment: Yeah, definitely a duplicate.